# Change Directory in MATLAB from Terminal/JAVA

Tags: java, bash, command-line, matlab, directory

I need to be able to change the working directory in MATLAB without interacting with the command window. I'm launching MATLAB from a Java application. Right now the only solution I've come up with is closing MATLAB, changing directory from JAVA and relaunching. Is there some streamlined way to send MATLAB the 'cd' command from JAVA? Doing so from the command-line would also work, since I could use getRuntime().exec(command)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but have a look at Undocumented Matlab (Google for it) which shows a lot of clever ways of interacting with the Matlab GUI which is itself (I think) a Java application.  That might give you some clues.

Comment: are you launching matlab or interacting with an existing instance? it's possible to control the directory it starts using a variety of methods: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f8-10506.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'd like to interact with an existing instance. Specifying the directory to launch from makes sense to me.

Comment: Are you also looking to execute code in the Matlab instance? If so, have you solved *that* problem yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using JMI if you're using the same JVM as Matlab (if not then I have no idea). There is not much online info about this (it's *WAY* undocumented/unsupported). Google it or read this: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html. In short, you need to include Matlab's relevant JAR file and then use com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab's functionality. For example:

`Matlab.evalConsoleOutput("cd('C:\Program Files\')");`

Yair Altman
http://UndocumentedMatlab.com

Answer (score 2):

I am working with Stephen Poletto who posted the original question. There wasn't any existing solution that met our needs so we wrote our own solution based off of Kamin Whitehouse's work mentioned by Yair. It is available for all to use at matlabcontrol.googlecode.com

It allows for controlling MATLAB from a Java program launched outside of MATLAB.