# Simple Interaction with an Active MATLAB Session from Outside MATLAB

Tags: java, c, api, matlab

I'm trying to give a Java application the ability to change the working directory within an active session of MATLAB. Basically, the user will press a button to launch MATLAB. Then, they will be able to press other buttons that change the working directory of the active MATLAB. I've tried a few different approaches, but with no luck. I've thought about calling on MATLAB from a C standalone, but this appears to operate in a DIFFERENT MATLAB session. Doing it directly from Java seems just about impossible. Isn't there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Please don't repost *EXACT duplicate questions* (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047283/change-directory-in-matlab-from-terminal-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COM interface on Windows to control a MATLAB sessions though a MATLAB.Application COM object. Examples and instructions are in the doc: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Stephen on this project. We ended up using a Java library I created called [matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com).